# Magento 2 failed connecting to Shipworks

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Magento 2.3.1 is failing to connect to Shipworks via REST API. The error it is giving is

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

When traced with Fiddler the result is

> {"message":"The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Sales::actions_view"},"trace":"#0 /home/buyglasswoodstov/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68):

I attempted reading through Magento Docs but I am very unfamiliar with REST API. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated to 2.3.1 this week and Shipworks worked on the 1st try. I followed the steps on their [support page](https://support.shipworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022465872-Adding-a-Magento-2-Store-API-v5-8-0-or-greater). Since I'm keeping magento 1 around until those orders are closed out, I had to buy a 2nd license and then migrate the 1st license via phone call to the new URL.

*Maybe this could be the culprit:* I observed that the backend only allows one login instance per username. I already knew this before trying to connect, so I created the new user. You also need to go to the `System => All Users -> User Role` tab and explicitly make the new user Admin.

Comment: I worked through the support page as well as contacted shipworks customer support and concluded it is something not working in my magento setup, but I have no idea what. In shipworks when setting up the store, my account connects fine, but I get this error message when I go to download new orders

Comment: Did you set up a different user just for shipworks and also make sure they are in the `administrators` user role? It sounds like that error is about user permissions. ShipWorks will use the REST and log in like in your Admin panel. If you are already logged in and your credentials are in ShipWorks, I could see how that would error.

Comment: I see what you mean, but yes I have created a new admin account specifically for shipworks and I still get the 401 error. Additionally I cleared all cache, completely shutdown shipworks and restarted my computer to ensure it was loading a fresh profile.

Comment: They are pretty helpful when you call them... please let us know the outcome for the next visitor.

Comment: Problem is still not solved. Worked with Shipworks customer service and have not found solution. Enabled FastCGI on Server in reference to another post and error is still 401 unauthorized.

Comment: How about shipstation.com ? I'm going to switch to them when I get a minute to catch up.

Comment: We are not interested in switching shipping software right now. Just looking for a solution to the problem

Comment: I tried connecting Magento 2 to ShippingEasy and ShipStation to see what would happen, and both failed to connect

Comment: Try checking the webserver logs as well as the logs under magento. I use `ls -alh` and watch the timestamp, too, to see what is updating with a page hit.

Comment: I have two errors in my system.log. They are [2019-07-10 19:01:07] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2019-07-10 19:01:08] main.WARNING: Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: {"message":"Handshake request failed."}. Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 [] []

Comment: Did you see this link: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection/td-p/129621

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it did remove the system error, but I am still unable to connect to any shipping software. There is nothing in the exception.log

Comment: I just created a fresh install of vanilla Magento 2 on the same server and still received the same error....

Comment: To quote what Alan Storm said to me: You should let them know: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: So now Magento is not authenticating for PayPal Pro when a credit card entered in the site, Shipworks Rest Api is still not authenticating and neither is Shipworks Module. I'm attempting to load everything on a new server to see if anything changes

Comment: Additionally I got this error in the system log main.WARNING: Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: {"message":"Handshake request failed."}.